# Do all "prefixes" can be use as "combining forms" or just some of them can be?

Tags: prefixes, affixes

I wonder if all English prefixes can be used as "**combining forms**" or just some of them can be play role as "**prefix**" and combine with other words or affixes to form "compound forms". e.g "***Chron-***" prefix can come at the beginning like "***Chronological***" (prefix example) and can be placed at the middle to form combining form like "***synchronize***".

Now I'd like to know if all English prefixes follow the rule or not and just some of them have the ability to use an place in the beginning and in the middle of words/affixes and the rest just can be placed at the beginning of words/affixes to play those roles just as prefixes only?

I like etymology and root of words to recognize unknown words that I face them in the articles or dictionary, so I started to create affixes, Latin and Greek root list in [Anki software](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) to memorize them one by one daily. Now I work and enter prefixes and tag them in Anki, but most of the time; I don't know what are those should tag as just *prefix* only or *prefix* and *compound forms* and this is confusing me?

Comment: If it doesn’t combine, it’s not a prefix.

Comment: @Lawrence, you mean all prefixes are combining forms and all prefixes can go to the middle of a word/affix to create a combination form?

Comment: No, I meant that prefixes need to be able to join up at the front of something to form words. If they can’t do that, they’re not prefixes.

Comment: But you can often use other prefixes in front of existing ones: re + in + force = reinforce. You may be able to argue that all prefixes can be pushed into the middle of some word this way.

Comment: If you use the ‘prefix’ as the stem of the word (as in your “synchronise” example), it’s no longer acting as a prefix.

Comment: @Lawrence, I got what you say and I don't say when a prefix like chron- in my example goes to the middle of a word is a prefix, of course "chron- in that example is a "combination form". But my main question is, Do all prefixes have this ability to goes in the middle to turn from "prefix" into a "combination form" or not and some of them have this ability and structure to be prefixed (at the beginning of word or affix) and also mix with other parts to shape "combination form" as well?